# Stuck in recovery while doing factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, recovery-mode

Having had problems in the past with battery draining too fast, I was advised to return it to factory settings. On doing this, it worked for a while.

Now the same problem has started occurring again. So, I thought, I would simply reset again.

However, I think, I may have pressed the volume down instead of volume up (or vice versa) as now I have a pic of the android and a message warning me not to turn off the tablet for the last 15 minutes.

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Please mention the device model and the version of android you are running to help you further.

Comment: Normaylly, you just have to access the following options: **Menu | Settings | Back up and reset | Factory data reset** (Note: These option may vary between manufacturers). No need to shutdown the phone and go into Download or Fastboot mode. You only use these modes to wipe the Android device and install a new firmware onto it.

Answer (score 1):

Your device is currently in either:

- (Non-Samsung) Fastboot Mode

  or...
- (Samsung) Download Mode.

In this case, because you're not actively transferring files, you *should* be able to safely reboot it.